# The this keyword is undefined in React base class

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I have a basic React app and I'd like to put some commonly used functionality into a base component class and have all my other components inherit from that class to get access to those features. I have this:

```
export class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.commonlyUsedMethod = this.commonlyUsedMethod.bind(this);
    }

    commonlyUsedMethod() {
        let x = this.someValue; // <--- 'this' is undefined here
    }
}

export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {
    onButtonClick() {
        super.commonlyUsedMethod();
    }

    render() {
        return whatever;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `super.commonlyUsedMethod()` from the derived class, `this.someValue` blows up inside `BaseComponent.commonlyUsedMethod()` because `this` is `undefined`. I'm calling `this.commonlyUsedMethod.bind(this);` in the `BaseComponent` constructor, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting? And where is the code that calls `onButtonClick`? Did you remember to bind `onButtonClick` to `this`? And why is `onButtonClick` calling `super.commonlyUsedMethod` instead of `this.commonlyUsedMethod`?

Comment: I agree with @JordanRunning. Why `onButtonClick` is calling `super.commonlyUserMethod` instead of `this.commonlyUserMethod`

Comment: @whs.bsmith so your components don't extend `React.Component`?

Comment: @robertklep
that's not what I meant.  I mean I don't extends my own component.  I am misunderstanding this article?
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all I (and most of the React dev community) don't recommend you to use inheritance.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Most of the use cases you have you can solve it using [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) or writing functions in a JS file and importing it.

If you still want to go ahead and do this.
You need to bind the `this` when you attach the buttonClick listener

```
export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {
    onButtonClick() {
        super.commonlyUsedMethod();
    }

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}>Hello</div>;
    }
}
```

Here is the working example for it. https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Knp4X-n1RrHY1TIaBN-

**Update**: Problem was not with calling super with proper `this`, problem was with not binding proper `this` when attaching the onClick listener. Thanks @Mayank for pointing it out.

Comment: can you please tell me what i am missing here, because it is working without `.call(this)`: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Knp7eAm845FhLPb_Mcf

Comment: You are right. I realized it now. Updated the answer

Comment: This works, thanks you. Is there a difference between calling `super.commonlyUsedMethod()` and `this.commonlyUsedMethod()`? In standard OO practice, you would use `this`. It does seem to work if you see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this a Good Practice™, but I can get it to work by calling `this.someCommonMethod()` instead of `super.someCommonMethod()`, like this:

```
export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    onButtonClick() {
        this.commonlyUsedMethod(); <--- changed 'super' to 'this'
    }

    render() {
        return whatever;
    }
}
```

I'm new enough to React and ES6 not to know if this is how this should work. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: But you would have to do super in the inherited class if you created the same named function there